# Set the comboBox dropdown width based on the values

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I set the dropdown width based on the longest string. My problem is, it does not display the full window, it cuts the text.

Code:

```cs
//Set the combo box dropdown width based on the values
comboBox4.DropDownWidth = DropDownWidth(comboBox4);

private int DropDownWidth(ComboBox myCombo)
{
    int maxWidth = 0, temp = 0;
    foreach (var obj in myCombo.Items)
    {
        temp = TextRenderer.MeasureText(myCombo.GetItemText(obj), myCombo.Font).Width;
        if (temp > maxWidth)
        {
            maxWidth = temp;
        }
    }
    return maxWidth + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
}
```

Please refer to this image below. Thanks

https://imgur.com/a/6kqodpD.png

Comment: Do you want the combobox to extend outside the window? That would be unusual.

Comment: Not a practical approach. What if a string width is greater than the screen width? Show the long items ( >= cbox.Width or so) in a ToolTip. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70289228/14171304).

Comment: Is that width actually equal to the width you set?

Comment: Im not setting the width what i do is base to the longest string

Comment: From the image you have posted, it's not clear what the problem is, because the borders of the ListControl are clipped. Does it go outside the screen's bounds? TextRenderer measures the Text correctly (unless of course the Control is scaled after that method is called, but you didn't say when / where it's called).

Comment: based on my image i want to display full text. and yes it goes outside the screen. what i want is display only in the forms or windows. or is there a way to wrap the text when it reaches maximum width

Comment: The ListControl is *floating*, it will expand outside the Screen and of course it expands outside the bounds of the Parent Form. This is the *normal* behavior. If you want to wrap the lines of text, you have to OwnerDraw the Items (`DrawMode = OwnerDrawVariable`), possibly using a custom ComboBox, to override `OnDrawItem()` and `OnMeasureItem()` -- Example here: [ComboBox OwnerDrawVariable Font format size problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103375/7444103) or applied to a ListBox (same thing): [How to add multiline Text to a ListBox item?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60589434/7444103)

Comment: See some important notes in the latter post, these also apply to a ComboBox.